# Como acrescentar Role em Cadastro de usuário?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC que usa **Individual User Account** e eu gostaria de acrescentar uma categoria (`Role`) pra ele na hora do cadastro.
O que eu tenho no momento é:

**View**:

```
@model Projeto.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Categorias</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select name="role" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                @foreach (var role in ViewBag.allRoles)
                {
                    <option value="@role.Name">@role.Name</option>
                }
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, a alternativa que vejo é usar o FormCollection.
Ficaria assim o seu `controller`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, FormCollection frm)
    {

        if (frm["role"] == "")
            ModelState.AddModelError("Role", "Erro na escolha da categoria.");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var currentUser = UserManager.FindByName(user.UserName);

                var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, frm["role"]);

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var allRoles = context.Roles.ToList();

        ViewBag.allRoles = allRoles;

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, um tempo atrás eu usei o exemplo a seguir, dá uma olhada se te serve.

http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/02/13/ASPNET-MVC-5-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-Roles.aspx